# Sanitize Windows 10 and remove residual application files

Tags: windows, windows-10

Whenever I find residual files or folders in my system and wonder where they came from, I go on a hunt removing every extra file that doesn't appear to be associated with a program I have installed through a Google search.

I hate doing this, it wastes so much time, but I want to keep my system clean. Especially the application data directory. It gets so dirty that I really wish application uninstallers would clean up after themselves. Top offenders are Visual Studio, NPM, and any and every application that likes to leave parts of itself behind after an uninstall.

I refresh Windows 10 frequently and start with a clean install every few months.

What software do you recommend to keep my system clean and satisfy my obsessive compulsivity?

Comment: [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com) does some system cleanup, though by default I don't think it eliminates application data. You can however configure it to do so I think. Otherwise use portable apps whenever possible so they leave no (or less) junk behind

Comment: I don't think you can automate keeping clean the appdata directory. If those are remnants of program removals, you could use IObit Uninstaller.